# Loading permission from manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have created simple android studio project with Google maps activity. My problem starts when I try to call `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` -> it needs to check permission from manifest, but I have some problem with loading the permission on `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Cant load it, it's red.

The method:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mMap = googleMap;

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        Log.d("mes:", "error");
    }
}
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="sei0055.placebook.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Starting with Android 6.0 permissions must be requested and granted at run time: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html - there is no "check from the manifest" for dangerous permissions. You are checking but not requesting.

Comment: "Cant load it, it's red" -- if you mean that `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is red, or that `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is red, you need to add an appropriate Java `import` statement [for `android.Manifest.permission`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html), just like any other Java class.

Comment: I mean ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is red

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {}
```